# Is there a way to display information from a connected table if not null?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I built a table with a MySQL backend in Django that lets me store generator charts that would be useful in worldbuilding and character building, like you might find on reddit.com/r/d100.  My table can account for 110 potential roll entries, but I anticipate that for some tables (such as d20 tables), a large number of the entries will not be used.  Is there a way to display all of the used entries but skip the null entries?  If not, I am prepared to hardcore each of the rolls to display on the webpage.

I was anticipating having to plug in something like

```
    <tr>
        <th>Roll</th>
        <th>Result</th>
    </tr>
    {% if table.roll_1 is not None %}
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>{{ table.roll_1 }}
    </tr>
    {% endif %}
</table>
```

This is my generator table model:

```
class D100Generator(models.Model):
    d_100_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    field_of_interest = models.ForeignKey(FieldOfInterest, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subreddit_post_id = models.ForeignKey(Subreddit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    module_id = models.ForeignKey(Module, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    generic_website_id = models.ForeignKey(GenericWebsite, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    table_name = models.CharField('table name', max_length=100)
    system = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    chart_type = models.CharField('Die used', max_length=15)
    chart_instructions = models.TextField('Chart instructions & explanation')
    roll_1 = models.TextField('1', blank=True, null=True)
    roll_2 = models.TextField('2', blank=True, null=True)
    ...
    roll_109 = models.TextField('109', blank=True, null=True)
    roll_110 = models.TextField('110', blank=True, null=True)
    table_slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            #Newly created object, so set slug
            self.table_slug = slugify(self.table_name)

        super(D100Generator, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.table_name
```

This is the view that calls the page:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

from .models import D100Generator

def index(request):
    latest_table_list = D100Generator.objects.order_by('-d_100_id')[:5]
    context = {
        'latest_table_list': latest_table_list
    }
    return render(request, 'generators/index.html', context)

def table(request, table_slug):
    table = get_object_or_404(D100Generator, pk=table_slug)
    return render(request, 'generators/table.html', {'table': table})
```

Comment: can you tell me, how you passing table data to template and what is the queyset?

Comment: I added the view code, is that what you were asking about?

Comment: Yes. another question, what do you mean by "skip the null entries"?

Comment: This table is meant to accommodate charts that have a person roll a die and then look up their result on the table.  If the chart calls for a twenty-sided die, there will be 90 unused rolls on the table that I would not want to show up in the table on my page.  I don't want the empty rolls being populated in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways to filter out the null entries for a column if multiple rows in a table are being used, but in this case I need to hardcode each successive column name, and there's no way to skip that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do as following to filter table data  to exclude null or empty roll containing entries

```
from django.db.models import Q

def index(request):
    latest_table_list = D100Generator.objects.filter(
        roll_1__isnull=False
    ).exclude(
        roll_1__exact=''
    ).order_by('-d_100_id')[:5]
    context = {
        'latest_table_list': latest_table_list
    }
    return render(request, 'generators/index.html', context)
```

This will exclude table rows in which `roll_1` is None or empty. Then you might not need check None in template.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time on this.  Your answer would filter out tables that have roll_1='', but I have 110 rolls to check for being null or empty string.  Is there a way to iterate through all of the roll columns in my table without hardcoding each individual column?  The answer may be no, and that would be ok.

Comment: Yes, then the answer is no. Basically the purpose of filtering is eliminates one or many rows, not specific column. so In this case you have to hardcode.